# Difference of exterior products in an exterior algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, modules, multilinear-algebra, exterior-algebra

Let $M, N$ be modules over a commutative ring $R$ and let $\phi\colon M\to N$ a surjective $R$-linear map. Let $(x_1,...,x_n) = (x'_1,...,x'_n) \in N^n$ and let $y_i,y'_i$, for $i = 1,...,n$, be some elements of $M$ such that $\phi(y_i) = x_i$ an $\phi(y'_i) = x'_i$. Is it possible to write the difference $y_1\wedge ... \wedge y_n - y'_1\wedge ... \wedge y'_n$ as the sum of $n$-fold exterior products such that every summand will contain $y_i - y'_i$ for some $i$?

Comment: Did you try writing this out for $n=2$? What did you find?

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, I did. It works for $n = 2$ since $(y_1-y'_1)\wedge y_2 + y'_1\wedge(y_2 - y'_2) = y_1\wedge y'_1 - y_2\wedge y'_2$.

Comment: OK, now continue the pattern to $n=3$ and the general case.

Comment: @TedShifrin I'm not sure how to generalize it even to $n = 3$ (tried that already)

Comment: $(y_1-y'_1)\wedge y_2\wedge y_3 + y_1'\wedge (y_2-y'_2)\wedge y_3 + \dots$?

Comment: @TedShifrin $(y_1 - y'_1)\wedge y_2 \wedge y_3 + y'_1\wedge(y_2 - y'_2)\wedge y_3 + y'_1\wedge y'_2\wedge (y_3 - y'_3)$?

Comment: Looks good, doesn't it?

Comment: @TedShifrin Yeah, I see a pattern. All terms preceding the difference are with $'$ unlike those following it. However, the question stand is to how to *prove* it for an arbitrary $n$. Shoud we use the multiplication in the exterior algebra for that (associtivity of exterior product)?

Comment: @TedShifrin I would like to post a full solution in 2 mins as an answer so you could tell me if I'm correct? Would you be okay with that?

Answer (score 0):

The credit is due to Ted Shifrin. We prove that
$y_1\wedge y_2 \wedge ... \wedge y_n - y'_1\wedge y'_2\wedge ... \wedge y'_n = (y_1 - y'_1)\wedge y_2 \wedge ... \wedge y_n + y'_1\wedge (y_2 - y'_2) \wedge ... \wedge y_n + ... + y'_1 \wedge y'_2 \wedge ... \wedge (y_n - y'_n)$ by induction on $n$.
The case $n = 1$ is trivial. We work in the exterior algebra $\bigwedge M$ with its multiplication $\cdot$. 
Assume that it is the case for $n \geq 1$. Then $$y_1\wedge y_2 \wedge ... \wedge y_n \wedge y_{n+1} - y'_1\wedge y'_2 \wedge ... \wedge y'_n \wedge y'_{n+1}$$ $$ = y_1\cdot (y_2 \wedge ... \wedge y_n \wedge y_{n+1}) - y'_1\cdot (y'_2 \wedge ... \wedge y'_n \wedge y'_{n+1})$$
$$ = (y_1 - y'_1)\wedge y_2 \wedge ... \wedge y_n \wedge y_{n+1} + y'_1\cdot(y_2 \wedge ... \wedge y_n \wedge y_{n+1} - y'_2 \wedge ... \wedge y'_n \wedge y'_{n+1}).$$ 
 The rest follows by the induction hypotheses and the distributivity of $\cdot$ in $\bigwedge M$.

Comment: Your dots should be wedges, but otherwise this is fine. Personally, I would have done the induction factoring out stuff with $1$ to $n$,  rather than with $2$ to $n+1$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks a lot for your assistance. As for dots, I've tried to distinguish between general multiplication product in $\bigwedge M$ and exterior products of elements of $M$

Comment: But the only multiplication I know in the exterior algebra *is* wedge product. I mean, you replaced the $\wedge$ with the $\cdot$ in your second line. You can't do that.